# Spring Boot and HSQLDB - look on database content

Tags: spring-boot, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I used `HSQLDB` in my small Spring Boot Application using one of the latest tutorials. I've created initial sql-file **schema-sqldb.sql** in resources folder:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  email VARCHAR(50),
  password VARCHAR(32),
  is_active BOOLEAN
);
```

and defined `spring.datasource.platform=hsqldb` property in application.properties.

Test method shown that it works just fine. But I can't see my in-memory database. Are there any ways to look on it via browser, console or any GUI? How could I customize it?

Comment: In order to browse a database created by HSQLDB at the same time that another process is accessing it, you'll need to run HSQLDB as a server in its own process rather than in embedded mode.

Comment: is there any way to look up on it in runtime? Like with some JDK tools or something?

Comment: This has been answered before. The answer is to start the HSQLDB DatabaseManager with Spring prior to your app. This allows you to browse the in-mem database. I don't remember the details though.

Answer (score -1):

yes its possible using DatabaseManagerSwing.

Please have a look at ->
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-view-content-of-hsqldb-embedded-database/

As shown in the example you can invoke DatabaseManagerSwing in Config class or in Listener (implements ApplicationListener) class too.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.